# how to save a JPanel as image while it is not Visible?

Tags: java, image, jpanel

I need to save an ArrayList of JPanel as images 
but i cannot do it because just one of them returns true for .isDisplayable() at a time and the rest returns false ... and could not be saved 
is there a nother way to do it ??
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your underlying goal with this, and I don't mean the programming steps you are taking but rather what are you trying to have the user experience with this bit of code?

Comment: my graduation project is about visualizing Network Optimization Models ... I wants to add a task that could save the steps of solving the algorithm on the graph ... is that what you asked for ??

Answer (score 4):

Try using camickr's [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

If that does not capture the image of the panels which are not displayable, I doubt anything will.

Comment: thanks, but I did not managed to get ScreenImage class to use it ... Do you have a link that i can use.

Comment: +1 :), @dawnlight - Whats wrong with the link? The blog entry contains a link to the actual source code.